# can't install burp suite inql extensions

Tags: burp

when I say install, it comes to extensions but it is not activated, when I want to activate it,

I get the following error:

It said it needed jython and jRuby, but I had already installed them long ago.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/.BurpSuite/bapps/296e9a0730384be4b2fffef7b4e19b1f/ext/inql_burp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from burp_ext.extender import BurpExtender
  File "/tmp/tmpDplVNA/burp_ext/extender.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpDplVNA/inql/burp_ext/attacker_tab.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpDplVNA/inql/burp_ext/attacker_request.py", line 24, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'

    at org.python.core.PyException.doRaise(PyException.java:198)
    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1337)
    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1341)
    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1345)
    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1349)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx5.f$0(/home/kali/.BurpSuite/bapps/296e9a0730384be4b2fffef7b4e19b1f/ext/inql_burp.py:83)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx5.call_function(/home/kali/.BurpSuite/bapps/296e9a0730384be4b2fffef7b4e19b1f/ext/inql_burp.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:535)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:286)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at burp.jkn.k(Unknown Source)
    at burp.g2d.I(Unknown Source)
    at burp.k4e.s(Unknown Source)
    at burp.hb.lambda$panelLoaded$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

enter image description here
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug.
There was a bug in one version of inql. Try to manually install this version
https://github.com/doyensec/inql/releases/tag/v5.0.1